# ReactJS: can not change style with changing state

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS(in fact I'm learning), I've written a simple code to check the style changing but as my best knowledge when the state change in react it will reRender the component but when I did this it does not happen, so I tried forceUpdate() and this work but the style does not change again,
I've tried this before with a simple state and it worked but when I set my style in an object everything got screwed up, thanks for any help

```
class Check extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sty: {
                width: 200 + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                height: 200 + 'px', marginBottom: 20 + 'px'
            }
        }
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    }

    update() {
        let sty = this.state.sty;
        sty.backgroundColor = 'red';

        this.setState = ({ 
            sty 
        })
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        console.error(this.state.sty['backgroundColor']);
        return (
            <div style={this.state.sty} onClick={this.update} id="checkBox" className="First">
                <span>{this.props.children}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Check key={1}>1</Check>
        <Check key={2}>2</Check>
        <Check key={3}>3</Check>
        <Check key={4}>4</Check>
    </div>, 
document.getElementById('container'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not use `=`.Use this.setState({...})

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
class Check extends React.Component{ 
  constructor(props) {   
    super(props);
     this.state = { 
        sty : { width : 200 +'px', 
                backgroundColor : 'blue', 
                height: 200 + 'px', marginBottom : 20+'px' }
         }
     this.update = this.update.bind(this);
 }
 update(){
   this.setState(prevState=>({sty:{...prevState.sty,backgroundColor:'red'}}))
 } 

render() { 
    console.error(this.state.sty['backgroundColor']);
    return (
<div style={this.state.sty} onClick={this.update} id="checkBox" className="First">
    <span>{this.props.children}</span>

</div> ) 
        } 
}

 ReactDOM.render(

<div>
    <Check key={1}>1</Check>
    <Check key={2}>2</Check>
    <Check key={3}>3</Check>
    <Check key={4}>4</Check>
</div>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: tnx for your help, but it does work properly even in this format(mean change the state value) but the style does not change yet

Comment: Do you want to make the color blue when clicked again

Comment: tnx, a lot, you are right, unfortunately, I have missed something, its working fine is this possible for to explain a bit why you use prevState and why it works but changing state not?

Answer (score 0):

In a  React component, `setState` is a function, you have to call it to use it.

Here is a working example of your code :

```js
class Check extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sty: {
                width: 200 + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                height: 200 + 'px', marginBottom: 20 + 'px'
            }
        }
    }

    update = () => {
        this.setState({ sty: {
                width: 200 + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                height: 200 + 'px', marginBottom: 20 + 'px'
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.state.sty} onClick={this.update} id="checkBox" className="First">
                <span>{this.props.children}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Check key={1}>1</Check>
        <Check key={2}>2</Check>
        <Check key={3}>3</Check>
        <Check key={4}>4</Check>
    </div>, 
document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'/>
```

A good practice would rather be to use CSS styling and make your components className vary based on his state

Comment: thank you for answering,  have tried your suggestion but the big problem is that you have redefined my sty object permanently but I want to change a special part of it (backgroundColor )and see the result in reRender, another thing that you said you have to call it, i cannot understand what you mean but if put this changing in my code it will work properly like this:

Comment: update () {
        

      this.setState({ sty: {
                width: 200 + 'px',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                height: 200 + 'px', marginBottom: 20 + 'px'
            }
        })
     }